# PHP: How do you determine if a file is a shortcut on Windows platforms?

Tags: php, windows, shortcut

Excluding any 3rd party extension not already bundled with PHP, Is there any method to determine if a given file on a Windows machine is a shortcut/link?  The built-in function `is_link` works only on *nix platforms, so the following ran on a Windows machine will not return what might be expected:

```
$filePath = 'C:\somefile.lnk'; // path to shortcut file
var_dump(is_file($filePath)); // returns true
var_dump(is_link($filePath)); // returns false
```

This would cause problems when trying to work with the target file of the shortcut, and wind up operating on the shortcut file itself.  The first four bytes of a shortcut seems to be typically `4c 00 00 00`.  But it doesn't seem reliable that this opening byte sequence is *always* limited to shortcuts.

*Side question:* how do you extract the target path from a shortcut file?  (Note: `readlink()` seems to return the path of the shortcut file itself).

*Edit:* just to save some trouble, the mime-type of shortcut files according to PHP using `finfo` or `mime_content_type` is "application/octet-stream", which really won't help.

Comment: On the `is_link` page, a [Windows workaround](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/function.is-link.php#91249).

Comment: Also windows .lnk files are just Desktop files interpreted by the Windows shell. NTFS has some real symlink and hardlink support. (Not sure if `is_link` deals with them.)

Comment: @Tim Cooper: I saw that.  Great attempt I think, but it was lacking any sort of citation for how that user devised that solution.  I also found several examples of reverse-engineering a shortcut file, but nothing official.  Maybe there's something a little more concrete to go on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as fill answer. Wrote that years ago, not sure if it works with current Windows versions.

For checking the magic bytes just use:

```
 $bin = file_get_contents("file.lnk", 2048);
 if (substr($bin, 0, 20) == "L\000\000\000\001\024\002\000\000\000\000\000\300\000\000\000\000\000\000F") {
```

And if you want to extract the path(s):

```
  function decode_windows_visual_shortcut($bin) {

            # taken from "The Windows Shortcut File Format.pdf" V1.0 as
            # reverse-engineered by Jesse Hager <jessehager@iname.com> 

            if (!defined("WIN_LNK_F_ITEMLIST")) {

                    define("WIN_LNK_F_ITEMLIST", 1);
                    define("WIN_LNK_F_FILE", 2);
                    define("WIN_LNK_F_DESC", 4);
                    define("WIN_LNK_F_RELATIVE", 8);
                    define("WIN_LNK_F_WORKDIR", 16);
                    define("WIN_LNK_F_CMDARGS", 32);
                    define("WIN_LNK_F_ICON", 64);   
                    define("WIN_LNK_F2_DIR", 16);   

                    function bread(&$bin, &$p, $bytes=4) {
                            $h = bin2hex( strrev($s = substr($bin, $p, $bytes)) );
                            $v = base_convert($h, 16, 10);
                            $p += $bytes;
                            return($v);  
                    }
            }

            $res = array();
            $p = 0x14;
            $fl=$res["flags"] = bread($bin,$p);
            $res["t_attr"] = bread($bin,$p);   
            $p = 0x4C;

            if ($fl & WIN_LNK_F_ITEMLIST) {
                    #-- don't need this
                    $p += bread($bin,$p,2);
            }

            if ($fl & WIN_LNK_F_FILE) {
                    #-- File Location Info
                    $p0 = $p;
                    $p = $p0 + 0x10;
                    $p_path = $p0 + bread($bin,$p);
                    $p = $p0 + 0x18;
                    $p_file = $p0 + bread($bin,$p);
                    $path = substr($bin, $p_path, 704);
                    $path = substr($path, 0, strpos($path, "\000"));
                    $file = substr($bin, $p_file, 704);
                    $file = substr($file, 0, strpos($file, "\000"));
                    $res["path"] = $path;
                    $res["file"] = $file;
            }

            return($res);
    }
```

http://code.google.com/p/8bits/downloads/detail?name=The_Windows_Shortcut_File_Format.pdf

Comment: Your `substr($bin, 0, 20) == ...` bit looks right so far.  But damn.  It might take me a bit to verify all that.  Let me get back to you.